# Unity 2D object position with touch position Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

i have a problem here,

i have an object called projectile and i want make that projectile appear where i touch my phone with screen resolution `1090x1820`, my logic is :

```
#pragma strict

var projectile:Transform;
private var shoot:Transform;

function Start () {

}


function Update () { 

     for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
         var touch:Touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
         if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) {
            shoot = Instantiate(projectile) as Transform;
            shoot.position.x = touch.position.x;
            shoot.position.y = touch.position.y;
         }
     }
 }
```

This code work well, except the projectile doesn't appear at screen.
Somehow, i try to put an object at unity editor and it's showing `x = -2` and `y = -1` or `x =-1` and `y =-5` and so on.I also try to Debug the touch position and it's showing `x= 300` and `y=90` etc.

How i can fix this ?

Sorry for my bad english !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are intermixing world coordinates with screen position. To fix that you'll need to use [ScreenToWorldPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) so your code would look similar to:

```
    var worldPos : Vector3 = camera.ScreenToWorldPoint (touch.position));

    shoot.position.x = worldPos.x;

    shoot.position.y = worldPos.y;
```

This is untested code so use only for reference as it is there for you to understand the logic.